# Azure Active Directory - Authentication Single Tenant

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, openid

I'm trying to configure Azure AD Single Tenant authentication for my web application.  I've followed the quick start guide for .NET, however I've noticed that I can actually log into my application using ANY Microsoft Office 365 account, instead of only those in my tenant as I want.

Can someone please point out my mistake?  I want this to reject logins that are not in my tenant ( @mydomain.com email address )

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
    {
        // The Client ID (a.k.a. Application ID) is used by the application to uniquely identify itself to Azure AD
        string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];

        // RedirectUri is the URL where the user will be redirected to after they sign in
        string redirectUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["redirectUrl"];

        // Tenant is the tenant ID (e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com, or 'common' for multi-tenant)
        static readonly string tenant = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];

        // Authority is the URL for authority, composed by Azure Active Directory endpoint and the tenant name (e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com)
        string authority = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"], tenant);

        /// <summary>
        /// Configure OWIN to use OpenIdConnect 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app"></param>
        /// 


        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
                CookieName = "My Workspace",
                AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
                CookieManager = new SystemWebChunkingCookieManager(),
                CookieDomain = "mydomain.com",
                ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0),
                SlidingExpiration = true
            });            
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config - as well as UseTokenLifetime
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    RedirectUri = redirectUrl,
                    UseTokenLifetime = false,                    

                    // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUrl,

                    //Scope is the requested scope: OpenIdConnectScopes.OpenIdProfileis equivalent to the string 'openid profile': in the consent screen, this will result in 'Sign you in and read your profile'
                    Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,

                    // ResponseType is set to request the id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
                    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,                               

                    // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
                    // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name or Id (example: contoso.onmicrosoft.com)
                    // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                        {

                            ValidateIssuer = true,
                            ValidIssuers = new List<string>() {
                                "https://login.microsoftonline.com/my-client(application)-id-is-here"
                            }
                        },

                    // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                        {
                            AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                        }
                }
             );            
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handle failed authentication requests by redirecting the user to the home page with an error in the query string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
        {
            if (context.Exception.Message.Contains("IDE21323")) {
                context.HandleResponse();
                context.OwinContext.Authentication.Challenge();
            } else {
                context.HandleResponse();
                context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
            }
            return Task.FromResult(0);            
        }
```

**My SignIn / SignOut methods in HomeController.cs**

```
 public void SignIn()
        {
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }            
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Send an OpenID Connect sign-out request.
        /// </summary>
        public void SignOut()
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
```

I'd like my application to ONLY allow logins from my active directory - not any office365 account.  I would also like it to detect if the user already has a cookie on the machine that is for another account and do like Microsoft does where they show a message stating ..."the account you are currently logged in with does not have access to this application."

Also, inside the Azure Portal, under my application in Active Directory Apps, I have selected "Accounts in this organization directory only (mydomain.com)" for the option "Who can use this application or api".

**Web.config**

I have the following keys in my web.config

```
<add key="ClientId" value="MY CLIENT ID FROM AZURE AD APP" />
<add key="Tenant" value="MY TENANT ID FROM AZURE AD APP" />    
<add key="Authority" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Although the application is still allowing logins from ANY Office 365 account, I have been able to add additional code to the `IssuerValidator` property of the `TokenValidationParameters`.  I'm not checking the JWT for the correct TID and IDP values that I expect.  Strange, even when I log in using an account NOT in my Active Directory, the TID is the same - however the IDP value shows up where it is not there when authenticating with a "valid" account.

Comment: That's really odd. Can you show what you have in your configuration for the authority etc?

Comment: @juunas - web.config info added.

Comment: At least one thing I notice is that value for **`ValidIssuers`** is not correct. This code `ValidIssuers = new List<string>(){"https://login.microsoftonline.com/my-client(application)-id-is-here"}` should change to `ValidIssuers = new List<string>(){"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your-AzureAd-Tenantid}/v2.0"}`

Comment: @RohitSaigal, I made the change as you suggested - no difference in result though.